# Animating Views from top-bottom to side-by-side in React Native

Tags: react-native, animation

I am trying to create a custom header for my app and I want to animate it in a certain way. I will describe the way it is supposed to be animated.

[image: Image with basic layout]

If you have a look at the image you will see one red `View` that contains one green `View` and a blue `View`. I would like the Views be arranged side-by-side from their current positions while animating.

I have tried to create the code for a collapsing header and the red `View` that contains everything, is shrinking based on a `ScrollView` but I cant get the green and blue `Views` to come side-by-side.

**Home.js**

```
const HEADER_EXPANDED_VIEW = 200
const HEADER_COLLAPSED_VIEW = 80

export default class HomeActivity extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)
        }
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "HomeActivity",
        header: null
    }

    render() {
        const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, HEADER_EXPANDED_VIEW - HEADER_COLLAPSED_VIEW],
            outputRange: [HEADER_EXPANDED_VIEW, HEADER_COLLAPSED_VIEW],
            extrapolate: "clamp"
        })

        // console.log(headerHeight)

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                        padding: 16,
                        paddingTop: HEADER_EXPANDED_VIEW,
                        color: "#FFFFFF"
                    }}
                    onScroll={Animated.event([
                        {
                            nativeEvent: {
                                contentOffset: {
                                    y: this.state.scrollY
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ])}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.title}>This is Title</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.content}>
                    .....
                    </Text>
                </ScrollView>
                <CollapsingHeader headerHeight={headerHeight} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    scrollContainer: {
        padding: 16
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        marginVertical: 16
    }
})
```

**CollapsingHeader.js**

```
export default class CollapsingHeader extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View
                style={{
                    height: this.props.headerHeight,
                    width: Dimensions.get("screen").width,
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: "#FF0000",
                    backgroundColor: "#212121"
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: "#00FF00"
                    }}
                >
                    <MenuButton />
                </View>

                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: "#0000FF"
                    }}
                >
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flexGrow: 1
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={{
                                fontFamily: "NunitoSans-Bold",
                                fontSize: 40,
                                color: "#FFFFFF"
                            }}
                        >
                            Home
                        </Text>
                    </View>

                    <SortButton />

                    <SearchButton />
                </View>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to React Native, please assume I know very little about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `headerHeight` at which it's going to collapse, then you could add a dynamic `flexDirection` to the `Animated.View` `style`.

```js
style={{
  /* ...your Animated.View styles */
  flexDirection: this.props.headerHeight < /* collapse height */ ? 'row' : 'column'
}}
```

Comment: thank you I shall try this out. As of now I have two components for the one enclosed in the blue enclosure, one that sits beside the green one and the other that sits below it. I am then changing the opacities of those two ```Views``` to make it look like it's sliding up, which to be honest does not look good